# How to avoid error not equal number in ggolot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to ggplot a scatterplot, but I'm getting this error:

ERROR while rich displaying an object: Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (463): label, x and y

My code is:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

#Data
fig5cwithoutdesc <- read.csv(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/learnseq/learning/main/fig5cwithoutdesc.txt"),sep = '\t',header = TRUE)

attach(fig5cwithoutdesc)

ids <- c("RPL31", "HSPB1", "MAFB", "ALPL1", "VGF","PCSK1N", "BSG", "CALY", "B2M", "SCG5", "TM4SF4")

ggplot(fig5cwithoutdesc,aes(a_donor, a_cell, color=(fig5cwithoutdesc[,1] %in% ids)))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('gray','blue')) +
  geom_text_repel(data=subset(fig5cwithoutdesc,fig5cwithoutdesc[,1] %in% ids),
            aes(label=geneIDs),force=19) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better using variable names rather than columns in `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

#Data
fig5cwithoutdesc <- read.csv(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/learnseq/learning/main/fig5cwithoutdesc.txt"),sep = '\t',header = TRUE)
fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs <- trimws(gsub('[[:punct:] ]+',' ',fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs))
ids <- c("RPL31", "HSPB1", "MAFB", "ALPL1", "VGF","PCSK1N", "BSG", "CALY", "B2M", "SCG5", "TM4SF4")

ggplot(fig5cwithoutdesc,
       aes(a_donor, a_cell, color=(geneIDs %in% ids)))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('gray','blue')) +
  geom_text_repel(data=subset(fig5cwithoutdesc,geneIDs %in% ids),
                  aes(x=a_donor, y=a_cell,label=geneIDs),force=19) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Duck, what's the benefit of the this line? `fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs <- trimws(gsub('[[:punct:] ]+',' ',fig5cwithoutdesc$geneIDs))`

Comment: @user432797 It removes any special character in your strings so that the filter can be enabled!

Comment: I found the missing values, they are about 10K, but still, I don't get the gray dots, this is the link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/learnseq/learning/main/fig5cwithoutdesc2.txt